# При задании значения в своём свойстве в xaml оно всегда null в конструкторе контрола

Tags: c#, wpf

Добавляю своё свойство в контрол, чтобы его можно было задавать через xaml

```
public class CheckBoxDataGridControl : DisabledRowsDataGrid
{
    public string ActionCheckBoxColumnFieldName
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(ActionCheckBoxColumnFieldNameProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ActionCheckBoxColumnFieldNameProperty, value);
        }
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActionCheckBoxColumnFieldNameProperty;

    static CheckBoxDataGridControl()
    {
        ActionCheckBoxColumnFieldNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ActionCheckBoxColumnFieldName", typeof(string), typeof(CheckBoxDataGridControl));
    }

    public CheckBoxDataGridControl()
    {
        ...
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ActionCheckBoxColumnFieldName))
            ActionCheckBoxColumnFieldName = "IsAction";
        ...
    }
```

В конструкторе свойство всегда null. Как что-то передать из xaml разметки в конструктор контрола?

Comment: В конструктор — никак. Действуйте в сеттере свойства. XAML умеет строить объекты только с конструктором по умолчанию, а установка свойств происходит уже после конструирования объекта.

Comment: Пробовал так. Чего-то не понимаю я по ходу. Всё равно привязывается как IsAction

Comment: Опишите подробнее задачу. Для чего вам это свойство и почему оно не Dependency Property?

Comment: Исправил код в вопросе (не доходит как вставить его в комментарии, чтобы Enter срабатывал). Это код уже после сообщения ("Пробовал так. Чего-то не понимаю я по ходу. Всё равно привязывается как IsAction")

Comment: >> Опишите подробнее задачу
Нужно задавать значение своего свойства через xaml

Comment: В комментарии код вставлять и не нужно, помещайте всю информацию в вопрос. Ну ОК, я вижу ваше DP, но для чего оно? И что-то какое-то ощущение дежавю у меня.

Comment: да, дежавю. был подобный вопрос

Comment: *Нужно задавать значение своего свойства через xaml* - ну дык задавайте, но я же вам говорю, что установка свойства произойдет уже после конструирования объекта. В конструкторе это свойство будет иметь значение по умолчанию (null в вашем случае)

Comment: я задаю, но не в конструкторе, а уже в методах это свойство всё равно имеет значение null

Comment: В каких методах? В вопросе нет этой информации. Добавляйте всё что нужно, чтобы понять проблему, в вопрос.

Comment: А это нормально, что я правлю вопрос в процессе разговора?

Comment: Вполне, в итоге должен получиться идеальный вопрос, имеющий всю информацию и не требующий уточнений в комментариях (комментарии могут быть удалены со временем, а вопрос должен остаться понятным)

Comment: В общем, ответом на вопрос будет: "В конструктор — никак. XAML умеет строить объекты только с конструктором по умолчанию, а установка свойств происходит уже после конструирования объекта". Использовал событие Loaded...

Comment: Т.е. всё-таки всё работает? Всё получилось у вас?

Comment: Да, я расставлял привязки в конструкторе (полностью код конструктора не приводил) из-за это не подхватывалось

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В конструктор — никак. XAML умеет строить объекты только с конструктором по умолчанию, а установка свойств происходит уже после конструирования объекта. Ну и не забывайте, что установка значений Dependency Property происходит напрямую (минуя обычное свойство, которое имеется здесь только для удобства использования в коде), поэтому для реакции на изменение свойства зависимости воспользуйтесь [перегрузкой `DependencyProperty.Register` принимающей `PropertyMetadata`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms597502(v=vs.110).aspx) и [конструктором `PropertyMetadata`, принимающим `PropertyChangedCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms557330(v=vs.110).aspx), в котором уже и выполните необходимые действия.